# Access Do.Cmd OpenReport is only printing?

Tags: ms-access, cmd, vba, ms-access-reports

Access 2010 - OpenReport in vba is only printing.

I have a simple modal form where the user selects a date range and the report opens. If the query results are 0, a message pops up saying there are no values, else the report opens and modal form closes. However, every time I run this it will not open in the report view it will only print. I can change it to design and print preview and those all work just not view.

I have been trying to figure this out with no avail and its driving me nuts. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
If DCount("*", "qryalltime_filtered") = 0 Then
MsgBox "No records to display based on the date parameter provided"

Else: DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAllTime", acViewReport
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAdmin-Employee"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to preview:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAllTime", acViewPreview
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to see it in the report view and not preview. I wrote the line again (like the 5th time today after restarting my machine) and I got this to work:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "RptAllTime", acViewReport
```

I have no idea why it worked after trying so many times. Ugh, Microsoft....

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this command :

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAllTime", acViewReport, , , acWindowNormal
```